# Copy constructor replace Move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I learn move semantics from [link](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/c-rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-beginners)

I have a class

```
class Holder
{
public:

    Holder(int size)         // Constructor
    {
        m_data = new int[size];
        m_size = size;
    }

    ~Holder()                // Destructor
    {
        delete[] m_data;
    }
    Holder(const Holder& other)
    {
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
        m_data = new int[other.m_size];
        memcpy(m_data, other.m_data, sizeof(int));
        m_size = other.m_size;
    }
    Holder &operator=(const Holder& other)
    {
        if (this == &other)
            return *this;
        delete[]m_data;
        m_data = new int[other.m_size];
        memcpy(m_data, other.m_data, sizeof(int));
        m_size = other.m_size;
        return *this;  
    }

private:

    int*   m_data;
    size_t m_size;
};
```

This class have copy constructor like :

```
    Holder(const Holder& other)
    {
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
        m_data = new int[other.m_size];
        memcpy(m_data, other.m_data, sizeof(int));
        m_size = other.m_size;
    }
```

And then move constructor have implemented like :

```
Holder(Holder&& other)     // <-- rvalue reference in input
{
  m_data = other.m_data;   // (1)
  m_size = other.m_size;
  other.m_data = nullptr;  // (2)
  other.m_size = 0;
}
```

I have a question :Why we do not implement  copy constructor like below :

```
Holder( Holder& other)
{
    m_data = other.m_data;
    m_size = other.m_size;

    other.m_data = nullptr;
    other.m_size = 0;
}
```

Could you please show me why this way doesn't use ?
Thanks

Comment: Why — because it doesn’t copy anything.

Comment: Note that `memcpy(m_data, other.m_data, sizeof(int))` only copy `sizeof(int)` bytes, typically four. I suggest you use [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) or [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) instead of `std::memcpy`.

Comment: Learn about shallow and deep copy.

Comment: Also note that `Holder( Holder& other)` can't handle rvalues (like temporary objects), while `Holder( Holder&& other)` (and of course `Holder(const Holder& other)`) can.

Comment: Because that's not copying a thing. The point of copy-construction... is to *copy*. Yes, it's a world gone mad, I know.

Comment: Why not copying i try Holder h(678);Holder h2 = h;   h2 still value

Comment: With the default copy-ctor compare the pointer values `h2.m_data` and `h.m_data`. They are the same, aren't they? In consequence every change you make to `h.m_data` will reflect on `h2.m_data` and vice versa. That's not what I'd call a copy of the object - they'd be more like magically linked Siamese twins. Also, if an instance of `Holder` has a `m_data` member that points to the same memory as another instance's `m_data`, what happens when the destructors run? Also please find a more reliable and thorough source to learn C++ from. The assignment-operator for example isn't exception safe.

Comment: @ledien `Holder h2 = h;` copy-initializes `h2`. Of course `h2` would have its values after its initialization. The object `h` on the other hand, with your proposed "copy" constructor, would not have any data. And that is unexpected for everyone expecting copy-semantics.

Comment: @ledien I wrote an answer. If you found it useful please consider voting/accepting it! (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I guess for safety reasons. Although what you described is allowed (and correct when one knows what one is doing), by doing that one could end up with an object which looks full but it is actually empty.

In general move constructor is more useful for using it with temporary values like:

```
Holder a_function(...){...}
```

Which then can be used for construction like:

```
Holder object(a_function(...));
```

Or to avoid reassigning/copying large amount of data/memory when doing something like:

```
Holder object(Holder(100));
```

But specially for this case which there is no default constructor (so in general every object should be full after construction) , by having the copy constructor as what you suggested (similar to move constructor) and then by doing:

```
Holder object1(100);
Holder object2(object1);
```

One would end up with `object1` which looks as a normal object but it is empty. Hence it could become source for bug/s later.

Although it is obvious, I should add that there would be no problem with the destruction of the object1. It is just that, using it in its life time, not being aware of its emptiness if there are not some type of safe guards in place (boundary checks) will most likely cause illegal memory access.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of that "copy constructor" is semantically something in between a copy constructor and a move constructor, which will be confusing and then dangerous. If your intent is to move always and never being able to copy an object, then you can force the class as being not copyable with this:

```
Holder(const Holder& other) = delete;
Holder& operator=( const Holder& ) = delete;
```

Even if you follow the rules for the non generation by the compiler of the default copy constructor and the default assignment, explicitly deleting  these methods is more clear.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding why _it will crash if "other'' gets deleted right after the move_ . Please explain?

Comment: I mentioned a problem in the move constructor, but it does not mean the fix should be there. It depends. At some point something is wrong and should be fixed.

Comment: @AKL, it will crash with that code: { Holder h1(10); Holder h2(std::move(h1)); }

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But I just tried it in many cases (with using ```std::move``` or without, also with several copy constructor arrangements) and no crash occurred! ```delete``` is supposed to ignore ```nullptr``` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete). And I think the move constructor is OK!

Comment: I also tried the case of deletion right after move construction by```Holder* hp = new Holder(10);Holder h2(std::move(*hp));delete hp;``` . Believe me, it is OK!

Comment: But I should add that I totally agree with the _making the class non-copy-able by using deleted constructors/assignments_ policy that you wisely  suggested if that is desired! And I think it is a nice and clean practice!

Comment: So how about voting for each other, dear friend? I am voting for your answer! :)

Comment: But please consider removing the non correct part from your answer. I just sent you the edit. Simply accept it if you agree!

Answer (score -1):

> I have a question :Why we do not implement copy constructor like below
>   :
>
> ```
> Holder( Holder& other)
> {
>     m_data = other.m_data;
>     m_size = other.m_size;
>
>     other.m_data = nullptr;
>     other.m_size = 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Could you please show me why this way doesn't use ?

Above code is not copying the state from other but moving the state/owned resources of other to current object being created.

from [Move constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)

> Move constructors typically "steal" the resources held by the argument
>   (e.g. pointers to dynamically-allocated objects, file descriptors, TCP
>   sockets, I/O streams, running threads, etc.) rather than make copies
>   of them, and leave the argument in some valid but otherwise
>   indeterminate state.

```
Holder A;
Holder B(std::move(A));  
// B is created by calling move constructor    
// Resources held by A are transferred to B  (ref1)

Holder C;
Holder D(C);             
//C is created by calling copy constructor
//state or resources of C, D are same and C can be used after this
//Object C usable
```

[ref1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)

Comment: Generally ```std::move``` is a simple ```static_cast```  to an rvalue reference type unless it is overloaded. It does not necessarily mean that the moved object has been  invalidated![std::move](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).

Comment: after std::move, move constructor will be called. Move means not copying. After moving you cannot use other object. Any operation on other object data is undefined behavior. That's why it is invalid.

Comment: *After moving you cannot use other object.* – That's a generalization you cannot make.

Comment: @nayab: _"After moving you cannot use other object. Any operation on other object data is undefined behavior."_ That's not broadly true. e.g. with a string or vector you can just clear it and carry on. Your own types may have similar rules. In fact the source object is **required** to be left in a "valid but unspecified state", i.e. no undefined behaviour.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just corrected the answer.